# What does "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory" in error log mean?

Tags: error, error-log

This page just started coming up:

**There has been an error processing your request**

```
a:4:{i:0;s:48:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory";i:1;s:2075:"#0 /home/dtacolle/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /home/dtacolle/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(313): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /home/dtacolle/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /home/dtacolle/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /home/dtacolle/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /home/dtacolle/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(169): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /home/dtacolle/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /home/dtacolle/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 /home/dtacolle/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 /home/dtacolle/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /home/dtacolle/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Config.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /home/dtacolle/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Config->loadToXml(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config))
#12 /home/dtacolle/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(260): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadDb()
#13 /home/dtacolle/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(270): Mage_Core_Model_Config->init(Array)
#14 /home/dtacolle/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->init('dtacollectibles...', 'website', Array)
#15 /home/dtacolle/public_html/get.php(113): Mage::init('dtacollectibles...', 'website')
#16 {main}";s:3:"url";s:91:"/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/o/con-dc-0007_2.jpg";s:11:"script_name";s:8:"/get.php";}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look at [PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory)

Check your "host" setting in

```
Magento 1: /app/etc/local.xml
Magento 2: /app/etc/env.php
```

> Try changing it from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"

Comment: Restarted the server and the site is back up now. Thanks

Comment: does anyone know what this is for magento 2? not seeing /app/etc/local.xml

Comment: @RobertSinclair... see app/etc/env.php

Comment: I resolved this on my local with ... sudo service mysql start

Answer (score 1):

Based on Renon's answer above but for For Magento 2 (since there was no /app/etc/local.xml)

You can change localhost to 127.0.0.1

> app/etc/env.php

Btw if you're getting this error while executing commands like "static content deploy" then another fix for this would be to simply execute your command using another PHP version (meaning: if you got Magento up and running but this command fails it could be a disconnect between the PHP version used by the command line vs PHP version used by your server)

So in my case, simply executing the command like the following worked:

> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.8/bin/php bin/magento
>   setup:static-content:deploy -f**

^ replace /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.8/bin/php with your PHP executable